# FFMPEG : Redirecting MP4 muxed data to socket using movflags resets timestamp

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4

I am using FFMPEG library to mux H.264 and AAC frames to MP4 file. I do that C program.
I store H.264 and AAC frame's timestamp in epoch format.

I use ffprobe to check timestamps that stored in the MP4 file, ffprobe confirms that file is in MP4 format and timestamps are stored correctly. below is the output of ffprobe.

> ffprobe -show_packets 20140805095931.mp4

```
    Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '20140805095931.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf54.29.104
  Duration: 00:01:39.70, start: 1407232771.984000, bitrate: 1063 kb/s
    Stream #0.0(und): Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 960x540, 999 kb/s, 30 fps, 59.94 tbr, 1k tbn, 60 tbc
    Stream #0.1(und): Audio: aac, 48000 Hz, mono, s16, 53 kb/s
[PACKET]
codec_type=video
stream_index=0
pts=1407232771984
pts_time=1407232771.984000 
dts=1407232771984
dts_time=1407232771.984000 
duration=34
duration_time=0.034000 
size=24556.000000 
pos=48
flags=K
[/PACKET]
[PACKET]
codec_type=video
stream_index=0
pts=1407232772018
pts_time=1407232772.018000 
dts=1407232772018
dts_time=1407232772.018000 
duration=33
duration_time=0.033000 
size=3180.000000 
pos=24604
flags=_
[/PACKET]
[PACKET]
codec_type=video
stream_index=0
pts=1407232772051
pts_time=1407232772.051000 
dts=1407232772051
dts_time=1407232772.051000 
duration=33
duration_time=0.033000 
size=3209.000000 
pos=27784
flags=_
[/PACKET]
```

My goal is reading this muxed MP4 data from MP4 file and send this muxed mp4 data to the client over socket without creating any temporary file. My actual goal is to write a C program though.

I tried using protocols tcp and udp but they are not working with Mp4 format and gives error as below.

> ffmpeg -i 20140805095931.mp4 -f mp4 -vcodec copy tcp://10.99.19.163:8888
>
> [mp4 @ 0xb1e1920] muxer does not support non seekable output
> Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument

So, I read somewhere about moov atom and tried it with following command

> ffmpeg -i 20140805095931.mp4 -movflags isml+frag_keyframe -f mp4 -vcodec copy tcp://10.99.19.163:8888

using above commandline I am able to send mp4 file to the client using tcp protocol that ffmpeg supports.

But when I apply ffprobe on the MP4 file timestamp resets to 0 , even starttime becomes 0.0000. Below is the output of ffmpeg.

> ffprobe -show_packets out.mp4

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'out.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf55.48.100
  Duration: 00:01:39.71, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1059 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 960x540, 999 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 16k tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, mono, fltp, 53 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
[PACKET]
codec_type=video
stream_index=0
pts=0
pts_time=0.000000
dts=0
dts_time=0.000000
duration=533
duration_time=0.033313
convergence_duration=N/A
convergence_duration_time=N/A
size=24556
pos=3853
flags=K
[/PACKET]
[PACKET]
codec_type=video
stream_index=0
pts=544
pts_time=0.034000
dts=544
dts_time=0.034000
duration=533
duration_time=0.033313
convergence_duration=N/A
convergence_duration_time=N/A
size=3180
pos=28409
flags=_
[/PACKET]
[PACKET]
codec_type=video
stream_index=0
pts=1072
pts_time=0.067000
dts=1072
dts_time=0.067000
duration=533
duration_time=0.033313
convergence_duration=N/A
convergence_duration_time=N/A
size=3209
pos=31589
flags=_
[/PACKET]
```

Any help or advice? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I have same problem. Have you haven any solution yet?